# android:layout_weight in linear layouts not dividing equally

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

Basically I have 2 linear layouts nested inside one vertical linear layout. There is a button in each of the child linear layouts. I want the 2 children linear layouts to be divided equally vertically across the page so I set each of their weight values to '1'. I know I could have just put the buttons in the parent linear layout but the first linear layout is horizontal because I want to put another button next to it so that there's 2 buttons at the top and one button at the bottom, and I want the heights of the top buttons and the bottom buttons to divide the height of the page in half. However this is the result I 
get

[image: The top button is clearly taking up more of the height]

The top button is clearly taking up more of the height and I dont understand why

Here is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15dp"
android:weightSum="2" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="0dp" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOffence"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_offence" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="0dp" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/buttonCoin"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:background="@drawable/selector_coin" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the main LinearLayout just change the values from wrap_content to match_parent, that should fix the problem (for the layout_width and layout_height)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="15dp"
android:weightSum="2" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOffence"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCoin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the layout_height of the root layout to match_parrent.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/holo_red_light"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCoin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
##main.xml##

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOffence"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="OFFENCE" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonCoin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="JUST FLIP A COIN"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```